# How do I animate moving shapes from one grid to another in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I am trying to animate movement between LazyVGrid views. I have two arrays of small Circle shapes (i.e. "dots") arranged in two different LazyVGrid Views (one on the left, one on the right). When the user taps a button, I want to animate each of those dots sliding from their original spot into their spot in a third LazyVGrid with all of them combined.

As if you had autonomous, but obedient, marbles arranged in grids in two places on a table, and when you command them to do so, they roll together to form a new grid in the center of the table (but simpler — no collisions, etc).

After many attempts, the following code is essentially my best attempt so far (though it looks dumb-ish out of context). The "Fill" button populates the original  but it still just animates like the original grids of dots fading out and new dots fading in, and then more new dots fading in as the first set of new dots slides up.

Any tips on implementing this type of behavior?

```
import SwiftUI

struct CT2: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = DotManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                HStack {

                    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 5), content: {
                        ForEach(viewModel.blueDots) { dot in
                            dot.dot
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    })

                    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 5), content: {
                        ForEach(viewModel.redDots) { dot in
                            dot.dot
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    })
                }

                LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 5), content: {
                    ForEach(viewModel.combinedDots) { dot in
                        dot.dot
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .foregroundColor(.purple)
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.addDots()
            }, label: {
                Text("Fill")
            })
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemFill))

            Button(action: {
                viewModel.combineDots()
            }, label: {
                Text("Combine dots")
            })
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemFill))
        }
    }
}

enum DotType {
    case blue, red, combined
}

class Dot: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let dot = Circle()
}

class DotManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var blueDots: [Dot] = []
    @Published var redDots: [Dot] = []
    @Published var combinedDots: [Dot] = []

    func addDots() {
        for _ in 0..<17 {
            let newDot = Dot()
            blueDots.append(newDot)
        }

        for _ in 17..<28 {
            let newDot = Dot()
            redDots.append(newDot)
        }
    }

    func combineDots() {
        for _ in 0..<blueDots.count {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                if let movedDot = blueDots.first {
                    blueDots.removeFirst()
                    combinedDots.append(movedDot)
                }
            }
        }
        for _ in 0..<redDots.count {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                if let movedDot = redDots.first {
                    redDots.removeFirst()
                    combinedDots.append(movedDot)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be able to use `.matchedGeometryEffect` for this. See the answer to [Use .matchedGeometryEffect to move button from point A to point B SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77055010/20386264) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was suggesting in a comment, `.matchedGeometryEffect` can be used for this.

In order for the dots to appear as if they are moving smoothly from one position to another, it helps if both the "before" and "after" versions can exist at the same time. When this is not the case, I found that the dots would move, but the before and after positions were not properly synchronized. This means, you can see how one set of dots fades out as they move off while the other set fades in, so the effect is a bit lost. I guess this is becuase the size of the `ZStack` is changing, depending on the contents.

In the updated example below, the dots are added to the combined array at the same time as they are added to the blue and red arrays. All dots are also displayed at all times, but the visibility is controlled using a boolean state variable that determines the opacity of the dots. The same variable is also used to determine the `isSource` flag for the `.matchedGeometryEffect`.

*EDIT* The effect can be greatly enhanced by shuffling the array of combined dots!

```swift
struct CT2: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = DotManager()
    @Namespace private var nsDots // ADDED
    @State private var showingCombined = false // ADDED

    private func gridOfDots(dots: [Dot], color: Color, showWhenCombined: Bool) -> some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 5)) {
            ForEach(dots) { dot in
                dot.dot
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundStyle(color)
                    .opacity(showingCombined == showWhenCombined ? 1 : 0)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(
                        id: dot.id,
                        in: nsDots,
                        isSource: showWhenCombined == showingCombined
                    )
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    gridOfDots(dots: viewModel.blueDots, color: .blue, showWhenCombined: false)
                    gridOfDots(dots: viewModel.redDots, color: .red, showWhenCombined: false)
                }
                gridOfDots(dots: viewModel.combinedDots, color: .purple, showWhenCombined: true)
            }
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: showingCombined)

            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                Button("Fill") {
                    withAnimation { viewModel.addDots() }
                }

                Button {
                    showingCombined.toggle()
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Text("Split").opacity(showingCombined ? 1 : 0)
                        Text("Combine").opacity(showingCombined ? 0 : 1)
                    }
                }

                Button("Clear") {
                    withAnimation { viewModel.reset() }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .foregroundStyle(.primary)
            .background(.background)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class DotManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var blueDots: [Dot] = []
    @Published var redDots: [Dot] = []
    @Published var combinedDots: [Dot] = []

    func addDots() {
        for _ in 0..<17 {
            let newDot = Dot()
            blueDots.append(newDot)
            combinedDots.append(newDot)
        }
        for _ in 17..<28 {
            let newDot = Dot()
            redDots.append(newDot)
            combinedDots.append(newDot)
        }
        combinedDots.shuffle()
    }

    func reset() {
        blueDots.removeAll()
        redDots.removeAll()
        combinedDots.removeAll()
    }
}

// other code unchanged
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: The effect can be greatly enhanced by shuffling the array of combined dots! Answer updated

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Is this something you've figured out through your own experience, or is there a collection of information somewhere that, if I'd looked thoroughly enough, I would have come across this `.matchedGeometryEffect` in due course? I find myself bashing my head against the wall a lot more often than I'd like, so I'm always curious how people find their way across bits of knowledge like this, where it seems like this basically perfect built-in functionality was sitting there all along, that I simply hadn't known about.

Comment: @McHobbes Pleased to hear the solution was useful, thanks for accepting the asnwer! I also first heard about `.matchedGeometryEffect` through SO posts. It is quite often used for [highlighting a selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77704378/20386264) or for moving the background in a [custom segmented Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750865/20386264). Some other [interesting effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077795/20386264) are possible too! However, it's also a common source of problems. The important thing is to make sure that `isSource` is always set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect with your views, you can make use of @Namespace and .matchedGeometryEffect

The modified code is as below.

```
struct CT2: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = DotManager()
    @Namespace private var namespace
    ... same ...
}
```

and inside each ForEach loops (you have three ForEach here), add .matchedGeometryEffect.

```
ForEach(viewModel.blueDots) { dot in
    dot.dot
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: dot.id, in: namespace)
}
```